# Same answer listed twice after being asked if I was a human

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was answering [Android, Connecting to MySQL using PHP: Null Pointer exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543726/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php-null-pointer-exception); when I clicked "Post Answer," I accidentally clicked the backspace a split second later, causing my browser to go back a page and then was asked if I was human or not.  I typed in the captcha and then I had two duplicate answers on that one question.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9543747/138383
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9543750/138383

Comment: Deleting one of your answers is the correct thing to do here.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug—from your explanation, it's clear that you submitted the post twice.

It's not a bug since the reason it happened is technically by-design (submitting an answer is a normal feature of the site).

I would be interested in introducing a feature that either limits the timeframe between which multiple answers can be posted on a question or automatically identifies duplicate posts on the same question.

Either way, most you can do is delete one of the duplicates.

Comment: Sounds right. I assumed it realized I was trying to submit an answer too quickly thus asking me if I was human...but I didn't realize it took my first answer so I filled in the captcha.  Then added the exact duplicate answer after I passed the human test

Comment: @AaronW.: Yup. Seems like there's a page that's requested mid-submission, which is probably the one that you visited when clicking backspace. The automatic system detected you were posting consecutively within a short period of time so it ran the verification.

Comment: There used to be a system that detected exact duplicate answers. Looks like that is no more then.

Comment: @MartinSmith Duplicate answers are still detected, but they get an automatic flag when the same exact answer is given for different questions.